# Absorption of glucose in small intestine

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology

During the absorption of glucose in the small intestine, glucose enters the epithelium by Na+/glucose co-transporter by the concentration gradient of Na+. The gradient is generated by pumping 3Na+ out each time and the entrance of 2K+ by Na+/K+ pump. The K+ is then removed by the concentration gradient via the potassium channel protein.

My question is is it more favorable to use a Na+ channel protein to pump Na+ out of the cell to generate the concentration gradient? Or there are some biological **significance** for K+ to enter the cell and leave again repeatedly (e.g. maintain stable charge distribution in and out of the cells? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na+ channel proteins would not be able to generate a concentration gradient, as they are [passive transporters](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22454/#:%7E:text=Sodium%20ions%20pass%20through%20specific,barrier%20formed%20by%20membrane%20proteins.&text=It%20is%20also%20called%20passive,contribution%20by%20the%20transport%20system.), not pumps. They essentially can only facilitate diffusion of Na+ down a gradient. The Na+/K+ pump is ATP-driven, providing active transport needed to establish or maintain a concentration gradient.